# EntityFramework Data Annotations required null integer

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a small question about EntityFramework Data Annotations (Code First).

I want to make integer / decimal required.

```
[Required]
public int? Nummer { get; set; }
```

But I have a small problem with this. The integer can't be null in my WPF application. Look at the screenshot bellow:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI98H.png]

Because of the required the property wont change to null when the textbox is empty.
It's clearly visible the Selected row still has a number, 3 while it should be empty...

I don't have this problems with 'required' strings.

[image]

Why is this a problem? Because now the Opslaan (save) button doesn't get disabled when the number is 'empty'.

I can fix this by doing my data validation again manually.
With a switch and the IDataErrorInfo implementation.

Does someone know if I can solve this with the aid of the Data Annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update your binding of your text box like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Nummer, TargetNullValue=''}"/>
```

With this binding the `Nummer` property gets set to `null` when the value of the text box is an empty string. If you don't specify `TargetNullValue`, the empty string cannot be converted to an `int?` and therefore you get a conversion error.

Just a question to get you right: When you want your `Nummer` to be required, why do you use `int?` as the data type instead of `int`?

Comment: Thanks it solved it! Really appreciate it!
 This is because in the frontend Nummer should be able to be null.

Your answer also only works when you use int?. Otherwise number can't be null and it's still the same problem!